# How to create a relationship between Item and Owner where owner can be a person or a company

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

In my app, an Item is owned by an owner where the owner can be one or more persons or companies, but not both at the same time.  Person and Company are two different models.  I would also like to use Ownership through model to associate some important information such as date of ownership, date of disposal, etc.

How do you model that in Django?  I am using Postgres 9.1

Answer (score 0):

A way of doing so is using the built-in `django.contrib.contenttype` app that supports 'Generics', i.e. foreign keys that may point to one of several models. It is very powerful because it provides form elements such as inline forms.

Here are a few resources about generics:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations-in-admin
http://screamingatmyscreen.com/2012/6/django-and-generic-relations/

Answer (score 0):

I have had a lot of success using [django-polymorphic](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) in my own projects, and it's very easy to use.

As of version 0.9.2, you can implement polymorphic models like so (taken straight from docs):

```
from polymorphic.models import PolymorphicModel

class Project(PolymorphicModel):
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class ArtProject(Project):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class ResearchProject(Project):
    supervisor = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Creating models:

```
>>> Project.objects.create(topic="Department Party")
>>> ArtProject.objects.create(topic="Painting with Tim", artist="T. Turner")
>>> ResearchProject.objects.create(topic="Swallow Aerodynamics", supervisor="Dr. Winter")
```

Getting polymorphic query results:

```
>>> Project.objects.all()
[ <Project:         id 1, topic "Department Party">,
  <ArtProject:      id 2, topic "Painting with Tim", artist "T. Turner">,
  <ResearchProject: id 3, topic "Swallow Aerodynamics", supervisor "Dr. Winter"> ]
```

---

So in your case, you could set up models like so:

```
class Owner(PolymorphicModel):
    date_of_ownership = ...
    date_of_disposal = ...

class Person(Owner):
    pass

class Company(Owner):
    pass

class Item(models.Model):
    owner = ForeignKey(Owner)
```